# sidewaystable and resizebox

Tags: tables, rotating, sidewaystable

I have a big square table 26*26, and I'm trying to display it in one single page. I'm wondering if there is a way to combine \sidewaystable and \resizebox. I'm trying but without being able to solve my issue. Do you have any suggestions?

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,  twoside, openright]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=3.5cm,bottom=3cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small}
\usepackage{topfront}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{rotating}


\begin{sidewaystable}
\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{table}[h]
\tiny
\centering
\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{p{5em}rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrp{5em}r}
\multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{ddddddddd ddddddd} &    \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{\% ddddddddddddddddddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd} & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd} & ddddddddddddddddddddddd & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd} \\
\multicolumn{1}{r}{} &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
ddddddddd ddddddd & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
\% ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{-0.5888} & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{0.5819} & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1     &       &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{0.1969} & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1     &       &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1     &       &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{0.0722} & 1     &       &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{0.1455} & 1     &       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1     &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & \multicolumn{1}{p{5em}}{-0.0579} & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1     & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & \multicolumn{1}{r}{1} &  \\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.1519 & 1 \\
\end{tabular}%
 \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%
}
 \end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For sure, don't nest a `table` environment inside a `sidewaystable` environment. Do get rid of both `begin{table}` statemetns as well as the lone `\end{table}` statement.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly doubt that your readers will appreciate being shown a 25x25 correlation matrix on a single page, displayed at a teeny-weeny font size. Odds are that they'll avert their gaze and hurriedly skip ahead to the next page...

But, if you have reason to believe that they might at least appreciate the typesetting effort, I suggest you rotate all 25 header labels in the first row by 90 degrees, counterclockwise. (Otherwise, the labels will get hopelessly entangled.) And, do load the `siunitx` package and employ that package's `S` column type for the 25 (not 26) data columns. That way, the numbers will be aligned on their respective decimal markers.
[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[top=3.5cm,bottom=3cm,hmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small}
\usepackage{topfront}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{rotating} % for "sidewaystable" environment
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for "S" column type
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{25$\times$25 correlation matrix}
\label{tab:addlabel}
\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{%
\tiny
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{24}{S[table-format=-1.4]}
                            S[table-format=-1.0] @{}}
& {\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddd ddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{\% ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} &
{\rotatebox{90}{ddddddddddddddddddddddd}} \\[1ex]
ddddddddd ddddddd & 1 \\
\% ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & 1\\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1\\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1\\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1\\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1\\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1\\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1\\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1\\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1\\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1\\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1\\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1\\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1\\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1\\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.5888 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1\\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 0.5819 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1\\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 0.1969 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1\\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1\\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 0.0722 & 1\\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 0.1455 & 1\\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1\\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0579 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1\\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & 1\\
ddddddddddddddddddddddd & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.0034 & -0.1519 & 1\\
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: do you have in mind a different solution? something like splitting it into two pages? how would you suggest to do it?

Comment: @ggg - I would start by (i) showing only 3 decimals rather than 4 and (ii) using much shorter labels/variable names. In addition, I would urge you to think hard about what you expect your readers to “get” out of being shown  24*23/2 correlation coefficients. Would they be better off being told about just 3 or 4 correlation coefficients?

Comment: it is placed in the Appendix of a long reserach report. Basically in the text i referred only to the most relevant correlation and I refer to this table for more detail. but you are right, i will follow your suggestion about label and decimals.